# Using openSession() over getCurrentSession() - when and why?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

This question is in relation to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048285/committing-a-database-change-in-isolation-to-the-main-transaction) I have asked, but what are the reasons as to why you would use openSession() over getCurrentSession()?  I know you would use openSession() so that you could self-manage the closing and flushing of the session, however, why would you want to do this manually?

I have used openSession() when I wanted to perform a transaction in isolation to the current session though I am not sure if this is a correct use of openSession().

Why would you want multiple sessions open?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know you would use openSession() so that you could self-manage the closing and flushing of the session, however, why would you want to do this manually?

One would use `openSession()` to implement [long conversations](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Sessionsandtransactions#Implementing_long_Conversations) (i.e. when you want to use use a **single** Session for **several database transactions** aka the extended Session pattern).

> I have used openSession() when I wanted to perform a transaction in isolation to the current session though I am not sure if this is a correct use of openSession().

Hmm... What? Transaction and Session are different concepts. What do you mean exactly?

> Why would you want multiple sessions open?

That's not the intention.

#### References

- Hibernate Core Reference Documentation

  - [11.1.2. Long conversations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics-apptx)
- Hibernate Wiki

  - [Sessions and transactions](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Sessionsandtransactions)

Comment: Thanks Pascal. Obviously what I'm doing to resolve my issue in my previous post is incorrect. I have a transaction that I start at point A in the code. I commit that transaction at point B. However within that transaction I need to update and commit a value in the db regardless of whether point B is reached (eg. app crashes or user terminates app manually prior to B). It looks like I can achieve this by opening a new session and starting and committing a transaction "inside" of the A -> B transaction. This didn't sound right to me to achieve an isolated transaction within the main transaction.

Answer (score 0):

We know that there were two ways to create/get session from SessionFactory class. 1) Using opensSession() method and getCurrentSession() method.

These are the below differences,

**openSession():-**

- It will create new Session object.
- You need to explicitly flush and close session objects.
- In single threaded environment , It is slower than getCurrentSession method.
- No need to configure any property to call this method.

**getCurrentSession():-**

- It creates a new Session if session doesn't exists , else it will use same session which is in current hibernate context.
- No need to flush and close session objects, it will be automatically taken care by Hibernate internally.
- In single threaded environment , It is faster than getOpenSession() method.
- Need to configure additional property “hibernate.current_session_context_class” to call getCurrentSession() method, otherwise it will throw an exception.